# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [29100, 27300]

Tags: python, regression, data-science, linear-regression

The dataset is from a survey about 91 art pieces from 300 people. The first 91 columns are the preference ratings for each painting scored 1-7. The 91 columns after that are their ratings for the “energy” of the painting. Additionally, there are more columns that represent demographic information of each person. I am supposed to create a regression model to predict preference rating from energy rating and demographic. I was able to do a single regression with this code but multiple isnt working. What's wrong?

```
rate = data[:,0:91] #isolate preference ratings
energy = data[:,91:182] #isolate energy ratings
demo = data[:,215:221] #isolate demographic ratings
demo[np.isnan(demo)] = 4.68
comb = np.concatenate((energy,demo),axis=1)
x = comb.reshape(-1,1)
y = rate.reshape(-1,1)
ourModel = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
rSq = ourModel.score(x,y)
slope = ourModel.coef_
intercept = ourModel.intercept_
yHat = slope * x + intercept
print(rSq)

plt.plot(x,y,'o',)
plt.xlabel('Energy + Demographic') 
plt.ylabel('Preference')  
plt.plot(x,yHat,color='orange',linewidth=3)
plt.title('Predicting Art Preference from Energy and Demographic') 
plt.show()
```

It is an issue with the reshaping but I've tried a lot of things and to no avail.

```
  File "/Users/pwigglybie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "/Users/pwigglybie/Downloads/CapstoneProject.py", line 132, in <module>
    ourModel = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)

  File "/Users/pwigglybie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/_base.py", line 684, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(

  File "/Users/pwigglybie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 596, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)

  File "/Users/pwigglybie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 1092, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)

  File "/Users/pwigglybie/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 387, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [29100, 27300]
```

Comment: X and y become incompatible because you have reshaped combi and rate to 1d vectors. Can you try the same without reshaping your array

Comment: then i get 
''ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (91,97) (300,97)''